# How to ensure classes references in a defaults.css stylesheet are compiled into a swc

Tags: apache-flex, compc

I am using compc in an ant to task to compile a theme swc. This theme swc depends on some asset swcs and in the defaults.css style sheet I refer to some of the classes in these asset swcs.

The linkage I use for the asset swcs is compiler.library-path but it seems that the referred to classes and not compiled into the theme swc.

I include my stylesheet using include-file and with defaults-css-url.

When I build my application that uses this theme swc I get a class not found error for the class in the asset swc.

The easy solution is of course to have my application depend on the asset swc but I don't wnat to do that. All of the assets that the theme requires should be included in the theme swc. I also don't want to bloat my theme swc by including all the classes in the asset swc by using compiler.include-libraries.

Answer (score 0):

ant example code:

```
<target name="compile" description="Builds the SWC">
    <mkdir dir="${dist}" />
    <compc output="${dist}/${library.name}.swc"
        fork="true" debug="false" warn-no-constructor="false">
        <source-path path-element="${src.dir}" />
        <external-library-path dir="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/libs">
            <include name="player/9/playerglobal.swc" />   
            <include name="datavisualization.swc" />   
            <include name="framework.swc" />   
            <include name="rpc.swc" />   
            <include name="utilities.swc" />
        </external-library-path>
        <compiler.library-path dir="${basedir}/libs" append="true">
            <include name="*.swc" />
        </compiler.library-path>
        <include-file name="defaults.css" path="${src.dir}/defaults.css" />
        <keep-as3-metadata name="Bindable" />
        <keep-as3-metadata name="Managed" />
        <keep-as3-metadata name="ChangeEvent" />
        <keep-as3-metadata name="NonCommittingChangeEvent" />
        <keep-as3-metadata name="Transient" />
        <jvmarg line="${compc.jvm.args}" />
    </compc>
</target>
```

hope help for you

Comment: Nope, same issue I'm afraid. That's basically how I have my ant script set up already.